# highlight the specific text everytime it occurs in the docx file using python

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

I have docx file i want to highlight the specific text everytime it  occurs in the docx file using python .
previous text is like this
[image]

after editing it should look like this
[image]

Comment: So now we know your objective, what's your question?

Comment: I don't how to do it in python .I am beginner to python and python-docx.